# Execute SQL to get some info

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, data-explorer

Is there any way to know the answer for this queries

- User with maximum points
- Question with maximum points
- Question with minimum points
- Answer with maximum points
- Question with maximum comments

Comment: The answer to #1 is always Jon Skeet.

Comment: You can answer the first three directly from the site.

Comment: You can get the 4th one with [is:answer, sorted by votes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer)

Comment: @jadarnel27 it's possible for an answer with less votes than another to have more points due to the bounty system (though that isn't the case).

Comment: @vcsjones Ah, that's true.  I assumed that "highest score" was what the OP meant by "maximum points."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to answer all these questions. The data isn't realtime, it can get stale up to a month.

Here is an [example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76204/which-question-has-the-most-comments) which answers, "Which question has the most comments"?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, go [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and write your queries. The schema documentation is over on the right-hand side.

But the answers to some of your questions are available in the Stack UI; for example push the "Users" button up there and sort according to whatever criteria you like.